# Google pre-launch report - Multiple items have the same description

Tags: android, android-dialog, accessibility

Google now provides a 'Pre-Launch Report' when a new Beta version of an app is uploaded to the Play Store. My last Pre-Launch reports contained a complete dialog full of '**Multiple items have the same description**'. I have now found out what, in my case, caused the problem and my solution. A simplified layout for my dialog that still showed the problem is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/displayHeightLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/displayHeightLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="@string/displayInfoEms"
            android:labelFor="@id/displayHeight"
            android:text="@string/displayHeightLbl" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/displayHeight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="@string/displayInfoEms" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <Button
         android:id="@+id/displayInfoOkBtn"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="dismissDisplayInfos"
         android:text="@string/btnOk" />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Google documentation suggested installing TalkBack and Accessibility Scanner, which enabled me to test and reproduce the problem. The solution is documented below.

Answer (score 1):

The solution lay in adding

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

to the definition of the second TextView, as follows:

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/displayHeight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:ems="@string/displayInfoEms" />
```

I assume that the reason for the report is that the first TextView contains an `android:labelFor` attribute, referring to the second TextView, and that the Accessibility Scanner looks at both and thinks that the descriptions are the same. Is this a bug in the Accessibility Scanner?